# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n!(\frac{x}{n})^n$ convergent for $x\ge 0$?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $u_n=n!(\frac{x}{n})^n$ 
then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{x}{e}$$
So when $0\le x\lt e$, it's convergent.
And I  stuck in the case when $x=e$.

Comment: Do you know Stirling's formula?

Comment: Just what is your question? Are you asking whether or not your series converges for $x=e$? That is not what your title asks.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes, maybe I needn't post the part that I already solved.

Comment: @DanielFischer Nope. I'd better go to Wikipedia first to find out what is Stirling's formula.

Comment: Okay, you actually don't need that. It suffices to look at $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$ for $x = e$ without taking the limit. Stirling's formula just gives you more precise information about the behaviour.

Comment: @DanielFischer Wow! Stirling's formula is so powerful to solve this question. Thanks:)

Comment: @DanielFischer uhh...If I don't take the limit, then is it still qualify D'Alembert's theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at the quotient

$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = \frac{(n+1)!n^nx^{n+1}}{n!(n+1)^{n+1}x^n} = \frac{x}{\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigr)^n}$$

without taking the limit, the knowledge that $\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigr)^n$ is strictly monotonically increasing and converges to $e$, whence $\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigr)^n < e$, shows that $n!\bigl(\frac{e}{n}\bigr)^n$ is a strictly increasing sequence, hence doesn't converge to $0$, so the series can't converge for $x = e$. Stirling's formula gives the more precise information that

$$n!\biggl(\frac{e}{n}\biggr)^n \sim \sqrt{2\pi n},$$

so the terms of the sequence converge (or diverge) to $+\infty$ for $x = e$.